# How to get vertices on a 3d curve with the start position, end position, start angle, end angle, and edge count given

Tags: 3d, angle, curve, vertices

I've got a program thats gotta get the vertices on a 3d curve when I give it the start position (XYZ), end position (XYZ), start angle, end angle, and edges. All I can do is get some lines to rotate in 3d :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not enough info. Many curves could be drawn with those parameters. Perhaps this curve is an arc (of a circle), i.e. it has constant curvature?

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, this curve has a constant curvature. It's not like a bezier curve.

Comment: What precisely is "start angle"? If it means direction, then you need two angles to specify that in 3D.